# For an Azure website running on the shared model what does "Up to 240 minutes of CPU/day"?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have searched around as many places as I can find and I cant find anything that explains 
this clearly.

So far what I think:
On the shared tier you may only have your website consume 240 minutes of cpu time per day.

On another page I found it said that the website is "spun down" 20 minutes after the last activity took place.   so if someone visits the webpage it will consume at least 20 mins of cpu/time.

If this is correct then on the shared plan you can only have 20 visits per day max.

Since that sounds absurd to me, there has to be a lot I am missing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The situation is not as bad as you interpreted it to be.

The 20 minutes timeout of the IIS site does not consume cpu if there are no requests happening. The 240 minutes CPU/day means that a single core may be under full load created by your site for 240 minutes.

So if you produce very litte CPU load with your application you can handle lots of requests/visits throughout the day.

Comment: does that mean if a single core cpu is never under full load bascially the site will be able to handle unlimited request/visits throughout the day?

Comment: @KevinL, no, your time under partial load will add up. If you create 480 minutes of half load you have also consumed your 240 minutes of cpu load.

Comment: @SimonOpelt, for an ecommerce site hosted on Azure website, how will I able to figure out what the 240 minutes of cpu load will handle per day? Like how many sales, users etc...

Comment: @KevinL, I will reply via [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17677452/468244) later.