# Hosting Nopcommerce Using Azure Website Shared plan

Tags: azure, nopcommerce

I want to host my NopCommerce ecommerce site using Azure Website Shared plan. However it says for this plan it "include 240 minutes of cpu capacity per day". Anyone have any idea how many users will this be able to serve per day approximately? I am clueless

Answer (score 2):

As this seems to be a commercial venture using the shared plan could cause unwanted, business damaging outages.

Some of the shared plan's limits (CPU, memory) can possibly be triggered by a short but intensive burst of requests. The required requests are significantly less than for a [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) which is kind of the worst case.

When a resource has been used over limit your azure website will be "switched off" until the calculation period for the limit has passed. For an online store scenario this would mean a significant service disruption.

Assuming that there are no unwanted or malicious requests at all, there is still no reliable way to guesstimate your resource usage from the information you provided. You would have to deploy the actual application with actual (or closely approximated) data, execute a large number of expected business transactions (e.g. start session, add to basket, checkout ...) and look at the resource usage the portal is giving you. Doing a proper performance estimation like that can even be useful for a reserved plan in order to determine the number of business transactions you can handle per instance per time before you have to scale up.